# AWS Elastic beanstalk custom image IIS deployment failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a custom image in AWS elastic beanstalk and configured IIS and Management Services as well. but when using the said custom image to deploy an application. the instance spins up and i can see the IIS welcome page but the deployment never completes and the environment stays in pending (grey) state forever. Any help on how i can resolve this is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to check the logs for error? You can login via SSH to your Beanstalk instance, and check the logs

Comment: This is a windows instance. you mean RDP to it?

Comment: Oh ya, forgot about that.

Comment: In Beanstalk, there is an option to download all logs, without getting inside the instance. Download the logs and verify the root cause.